# Why is my ttsx3 in Python not playing any audio

Tags: python, text-to-speech, pyttsx3

I am using pycharm and have pyaudio and pyttsx3 installed. my issue is the audio from my text to speech is not playing. I can see the text being put down in the console so I know that everything else works. Here's the code relating to the tts.

```
    import pyttsx3 as tts

    import speech_recognition
    import wikipedia
    from neuralintents import GenericAssistant
    import requests
    import pyaudio
    
    recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer()
    
    speaker = tts.init()
    speaker.setProperty("rate", 150)
    speaker.setProperty("volume", 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This It's Works For Me

Fist Install This If You Have WINDOWS OS:- `pip install pyttsx3` OR If You Have MAC OS:- `pip3 install pyttsx3`

```
import pyttsx3

def voicePlay(string):

    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    engine.say(f"{string}") 
    try:
        engine.runAndWait()
    except Exception as e:
        pass
    engine.runAndWait()
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to install 2 libraries

> For Mac or Linux
>  `pip3 install gtts`
>  `pip3 install playsound`

> For Windos
>  `pip install gtts`
>  `pip install playsound`

```
from gtts import gTTS
from playsound import playsound


def voicePlay(string):

    myobj = gTTS(text=string, lang='en', slow=False)
    myobj.save("tts.mp3")
    playsound('tts.mp3')


voicePlay("string")
```